# Alternative way to remove duplicates from CSV other than Sort-Object -unique?

Tags: powershell

I have a bug I cannot beat. When I run my script gets to this chunk of code it is incorrectly removing unique values:

```
import-csv "$LocalPath\A1-$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
    where {$_."CustomerName" -match $Customersregex} |
    select "SubmitterID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime",@{Name="Form";Expression={if ($_.FormName -match "Copy"){"C"};if ($_.FormName -match "Letter"){"L"} else {""} }},"TotalDocs",@{Name="AddnPages";Expression={$_.TotalAdditionalPages}},"InputFilename",@{Name="ActualDocs";Expression={[string]([int]$_.RegularDocs + [int]$_.UnqualifiedDocs)}}|
    sort "InputFilename" -Unique |
    export-csv "$LocalPath\A2-$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It's occurring during the "sort "InputFilename" -Unique" line, however it will work properly when I cut it up and execute it line by line, but not in the original script.

Is there any other way to remove duplicates based on the value of a column? I've tried using the "-unique" parameter on the Select-Object statement but I can't find a way to limit it to only one column.

**EDIT:** To clarify the issue I'm having, I have a LARGE list of accounting data. I'm trying to remove duplicate entries by using "Sort -unique". After the above code is running, there are entries missing that should not be because they are unique. I can isolate them in their own CSV, run the above code and all entries are present that should be, however when I run my master CSV file through the above code (and only that code, nothing else) and search for those entries they are missing.
**EDIT 2:** Looks like it was an issue with the data file. Good grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always group things, then expand the first item in the group. It's not fast, but it works for what you're doing.

```
import-csv "$LocalPath\A1-$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
    where {$_."CustomerName" -match $Customersregex} |
    group InputFilename |
    % { $_.Group[0] } |
    select "SubmitterID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime",@{Name="Form";Expression={if ($_.FormName -match "Copy"){"C"};if ($_.FormName -match "Letter"){"L"} else {""} }},"TotalDocs",@{Name="AddnPages";Expression={$_.TotalAdditionalPages}},"InputFilename",@{Name="ActualDocs";Expression={[string]([int]$_.RegularDocs + [int]$_.UnqualifiedDocs)}}|
    sort "InputFilename" |
    export-csv "$LocalPath\A2-$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my ISE it tells me that "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Comment: @fudge Sorry, code was edited, but not quite right. Try now, this should work.

Comment: This worked great, but it turns out it was an issue with the data file. I may try using this in the future.